# A compilation issue regarding constexpr expressions in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, constexpr

I'm working on a rendering engine using Vulkan and Visual Studio 2017, and I bumped into the following type of problem recently.

I have a template struct `template<uint32_t id> struct A;`. This struct is defined (in separate header files) for `id=0, ... , N-1`. All of the definitions have a `static constexpr std::array<B, M(id)> member` for some struct `B` and number `M` depending on `id`. I have a constexpr function (and a helper function) which for a given value `b` of type `B`  counts how many elements of all of these arrays equal to `b`. It looks something like this:

Helper function:

```
template<size_t Size>
constexpr void count_in_array(B b, const std::array<B, Size>& a, uint32_t& count)
{
    for(auto& e : a)
    {
        if(e==b)
            ++count;
    }
}
```

Main function:

```
template<uint32_t... ids>
constexpr uint32_t count_in_arrays(B b, std::index_sequence<ids...>)
{
   uint32_t count=0;
   auto l ={ (count_in_array(b, A<ids>::member, count), 0)... };
   return count;
}
```

When I compile, I get a C1001 internal compiler error. The strange thing is that my funcions work, because if I use them to define a constexpr variable

```
constexpr uint32_t var=count_in_arrays(b, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
```

(for a `constexpr B b`),
and I hoover the mouse over that variable, I see the computed (and correct) number in the appearing rectangle.

I am not familiar with compiler switches, I only tried to use `#pragma optimize("", on/off)` around the above functions, but that didn't help. Does somebody have an idea how to make Visual Studio to compile my code?

Remark: I am pretty sure that the struct `B` is not important here, in my case, it is a simple data struct containing some built-in variables.

Comment: Internal compiler error is always a bug in a compiler. So even your `struct B` might be important. It would be best if you were able to create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that produces the compiler error (and possibly report it to MSVC).

Comment: Yes, even if the compiler is going to reject code (because it doesn't support some newer feature, for example), it shouldn't ICE. One thing I would suggest you try is go into the project settings (Project -> Properties, go to C/C++ -> Language and set "C++ Language Standard" to either c++ 17 or latest. I don't know that will fix this but it may at least give you informative diagnostics.

Comment: At this very moment I don't know what MCVE is (thanks for the link), I'm checking it out.

Comment: I am using c++17, and (also tried latest) language standard. Sorry, I should have mentioned it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an internal compiler error is *always* a compiler bug. Please report this to MSVC.

Second, this implementation is a bit odd. When you write `constexpr` functions you want to think in a more functionally-oriented way - input-only arguments, output-only results. `count_in_array` should surely just return a number:

```
template <size_t Size>
constexpr uint32_t count_in_array(B b, const std::array<B, Size>& a)
{
    uint32_t count = 0;
    for(auto& e : a)
    {
        if(e==b)
            ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is a more reasonable implementation - `count` returns a count. Not only that, but it composes really nicely. How do you get all the counts? You sum them:

```
template <size_t... Ids>
constexpr uint32_t count_in_arrays(B b, std::index_sequence<Ids...>)
{
   return (count_in_array(b, A<Ids>::member) + ...);
}
```

Much clearer.

---

Note that, while I think fold-expressions don't quite work in MSVC yet (though might [soon](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7jdnfh/did_anyone_get_fold_expressions_working_in_either/dr60244/?st=jb5ibv25&sh=12a078dd)?), that in of itself is not a reason to implement this differently. It just means that you need to manually sum - not that `count_in_array()` shouldn't return a count.

Comment: I know about fold expressions, but as you wrote, it's not supported in MSVC yet and the implementation I wrote seems the most short and self-explanatory implementation to me, but I guess I will try the implementation you suggested. It's just strange to me that mine doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Sandor It's not strange, it's just a bug. It's not a compiler error that implies your code is wrong. Every software has bugs, even the compilers...

Comment: Ok, I get it. I'll check how to report this to MSVC. Thanks for everyone!